# controller not executing when redirecting to current route

Tags: angularjs

Say I have this controller :

```
function fooCtrl() {

    // initialize things when foo view is loaded
}
```

my controller will execute after this redirect

```
$location(/foo)
```

**But only if me current view is not foo.**

I would like the controller to execute after `$location(/foo)`, even when my current view is foo.

Is that possible ?

Comment: This question not clear what you actually do with this controller, please give details code example.

Comment: Are you using the standard `$routeProvider` or ui-router?

Answer (score 0):

If using ngRoute, call `$route.reload()` if `$location.url()` is the same as your target route.